# How to make a Demo-version of an [EA] work on a MetaTrader live-account?

Tags: trading, mql4, metatrader4, forex, metatrader5

I have an `ExpertAdvisor` ( <kbd>**`EA`**</kbd> ), named Hedging Recovery EA, it works correctly on my demo MetaTrader account, now  I'm about to create an account with a 5 USD deposit and about to deposit +1000 USD on it, but I'm not sure, if the <kbd>`EA`</kbd> will work, because I have heared that a Demo EA works only on a Demo MetaTrader account.

If it is true, how can I make it work on a live-account?

This is the executable format of the said <kbd>`EA`</kbd> :
http://www.mediafire.com/download/cezoct5m7cgqngm/Hedging+Recovery.ex4

Answer (score 3):

**FACT**: You're trying to use a commercial EA without paying for the fee. This is unethical.

**ANSWER**: Putting ethics aside, the solution to your problem is to use a CopyTrade software. Basically, run the EA on a demo-account (the EA allows for it), then copy-trade it into a real-account.

1. You can use a CopyTrade, there are some that are free, but mostly are commercial too.
2. If you are really **cheap**, you can open a Signal account in www. MQL5. com (remove the space), set it to free subscription, then subscribe your real account to it.

---

**On The Side** (not related to the answer):

a. If you really believe in an EA/strategy but cannot afford $99 for it, you should not be trading.

b. These type of strategy works well in a fierce-trend movement, but your account will blow in a ranging-market. Don't set it to auto-trade for you. It will blow after a while.

Answer (score -1):

### Facts:

<kbd>EA</kbd> authors publish, that:
- the code contains a remote-license validation protection
- the code shall never be used under other circumstances but only on relatively small account - with equity < $10000 and > $4000
- trading license costs $99, or $199 with code-adaptations, other options available

### Next steps: How to make it work on live-account?

1 ) Attempt to make your operations compatible with the said equity advice.
2 ) Choose a license type that best meets your expectations
3 ) buy the suitable license